# JSP custom closing form tag show on wrong spot

Tags: jsp, tags, formclosing

We are using JSP custom form tag, we found the closing tag `</form>` always shows in the wrong spot, which causes a lot problems for us because the following dynamically generated html elements are not nested inside `<form>...</form>` after the user submits the form, those elements data are lost.
   Here is the code:

```
   <ct:table>
       <ct:form name="form1" >
           <ct:addFromRequest prefix="<%= AP.CSA_PREFIX %>" />
           <ct:add name="<%= AP.ACTION %>" value=" " />
           <tr>
            .....some dynamically generated code here
           </tr>
       </ct:form>
    </ct:table>
```

In IE, it works as expected:

```
  <table>
    <form name="form1" >
    <tr>
    ...
    </tr>
    </form>
   </table>
```

But in FireFox and Chrome, it always show like:

```
  <table>
    <form name="form1" ></form>  *******the closing </form> tag appears here
    <tr>
    ... dynamically generated html controls here
    </tr>
  </table>
```

The whole page is code is here:

```
<%
CCtFormValidation ct_form = new CCtFormValidation( jsp_input );
CCtHelperFunctions ct_helper = new CCtHelperFunctions( jsp_input );
%>

<%@ include file="../../generic_gui/template/general_head.jsp" %>
<ct:script>
function CheckForm ( form_to_check )
{
    if ( form_to_check.<%=AP.MANAGE_GROUP%>[0].checked 
        && form_to_check.<%=AP.GROUP_ID%>.selectedIndex < 1 )
    {
        <%= ct_form.printErrorJavascriptAlert ( CFrontEndErrorCodes.FRONTEND_ERROR_CODE_MISSING_MANDATORY_PARAMS ) %>
        form_to_check.<%=AP.GROUP_ID%>.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
function BeforeSubmit( form_to_submit )
{
    form_to_submit.<%=AP.ACTION%>.value = "<%=AP.ACTION_SUBMIT%>";
}

function BeforeCancel( form_to_cancel )
{
    form_to_cancel.<%=AP.ACTION%>.value = "<%=AP.ACTION_CANCEL%>";
}

function OnLoad()
{
}

</ct:script>


<%@ include file="../../generic_gui/template/general_body_start.jsp" %>
<ct:table width="75%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ct:form name="form1">
            <ct:addFromRequest prefix="<%= AP.CSA_PREFIX %>" />
            <ct:add name="<%= AP.ACTION %>" value=" " />
            <span class="PageHeader">
                <%= rc.getStr ( "s_page_title" ) %>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><br><br></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <span class="BodyText">
                <%= rc.getStr ( "s_text_1" ) %>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><br></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="radio" name="<%=AP.MANAGE_GROUP%>" value="<%=AP.MODIFY_GROUP%>" checked>
            &nbsp;
            <span class="BodyText">
                <%= rc.getStr("s_modify_group_text")%>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="BodyText">
                <select id="<%=AP.GROUP_ID%>" name="<%=AP.GROUP_ID%>" size="1" class="textBoxNoSize" onFocus="document.form1.<%=AP.MANAGE_GROUP%>[0].checked=true;">
                    <OPTION value="<%=rc.getStr("s_select_group")%>"><%=rc.getStr("s_select_group")%></OPTION>
                <%
                    CCSAGroupDetails current_group;
                    for ( int counter = 0 ; counter < group_list.size() ; ++counter )
                    {
                        current_group = ( CCSAGroupDetails ) group_list.get ( counter );
                    %>
                    <OPTION value="<%=current_group.getGroupId()%>"><%=current_group.getGroupName()%></OPTION>
                <% } %>
                </select>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <input type="radio" name="<%=AP.MANAGE_GROUP%>" value = "<%=AP.CREATE_GROUP%>">
            &nbsp;
            <span class="BodyText">
                <%= rc.getStr("s_create_group_text")%>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
        <br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="50" valign="bottom">
        <td align="center">
            <ct:button param="button_next" javascript="SubmitForm( document.form1 );"/></td>
        <td></td>
        <td align="center">
            <ct:button param="button_cancel" javascript="CancelForm( document.form1 );"/></td>
    </tr>
</ct:form>
</ct:table>
<%@ include file="../../generic_gui/template/general_body_end.jsp" %>
<%@ include file="../../generic_gui/template/general_footer.jsp" %>
```

The page rendered on IE with right tag start and close `<form name=form1>...</form>` however, FF and Chrome page rendered as `<form name=form1></form>`.

Any problems with my code?

Comment: What does your custom tag do?  Do you have any exceptions on the page for IE like most others do?  Can you show the whole page rather than just a snip it.  At very least the header so we can see what the tag is associated with.